# Get a value inside a get_post_meta Array

Tags: php

I am editing a Wordpress theme and want to output a value that's inside an array in the post meta array.

My code is:

```
$banner_subtitle = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'header_section_meta', true );

echo print_r($banner_subtitle);
```

And my output is:

```
Array
(
[section_mode] => banner
[header_section_id] => 
[slider_alias] => 
[banner_subtitle] => SUBTITLE 1
[banner_image] => http://www.example.com/image.jpg
[is_banner_image_parallax] => 0
[banner_image_repeat] => repeat-x
[banner_mask] => 
)
1
```

How can I modify my code so that the output is the value of the **banner_subtitle**, in this case "SUBTITLE 1", instead of that whole array? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$banner_subtitle = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'header_section_meta', true );
if (!empty($banner_subtitle['banner_subtitle'])) {
    echo $banner_subtitle['banner_subtitle'];
}
```

or as a ternary

```
$banner_subtitle = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'header_section_meta', true );
echo !empty($banner_subtitle['banner_subtitle']) ? $banner_subtitle['banner_subtitle'] : '';
```

Comment: This code breaks the template. Not working :(

Comment: missed a closing parens.  fixed now

Comment: YES! The first code now works perfectly. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me!